# Exibir streaming de vídeo usando protocolo RTSP

Tags: html, html5, streaming, rtsp

Olá, estou tentando exibir a imagem de uma câmera IP que usa protocolo rtsp. Testei usando o VLC (software de vídeo) e funcionou, mas preciso exibir em uma página web.

Comment: Podes tentar usar uma biblioteca https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player

Comment: Boa noite, até já havia baixado está biblioteca, porém não entendi muito bem o funcionamento. Detalhando aqui, acessei o diretório: exemples/Index.html e alterei o endereço rtsp no parametro source. Executei mas não visualizou nada, player ficou tentando carregar. Testei novamente usando o vlc player para tirar a prova, e funcionou. Se puder detalhar mais deste projeto (lib) agradeço.